# taking form input / processing / returning information on another page

Tags: php, html

I have asked this question in a similar manner here before and got a mixed response.
Having done some more homework I feel the need to ask again as I am taking a far more logical view toward it.

I have a search box, I want to take the the query from the search submission, process it and return the result to an Iframe in another page.
Very much like a php email form, but with a twist.

**Ideal Scenerio:**

search box query > process the query( the query is sent to external server in a string and processed, then returned as a html page > page displayed in an Iframe on another page.

I would like any suggestions or example code would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Only some suggestions as I've not ready code to show you here:
this seems to me the ideal situation to use AJAX.
BUT I'd create and use a box (with div tag) rather than using an iframe.
You should bind your searchbox submission with a function that make the ajax call to a script that process the search parameters and provide you with results.
Once results are ready, your function callback will make them appear in your box (modifying the inner html contents of the box).

I think MAYBE you could get same result with an Iframe but, personally, I don't like using frames.

Hope to have helped you.

Here for you [a little ajax tutorial showing just something like the thing you need](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Comment: the query string is sent to an off site server and with ajax I have ran into cross site security issues. I load into an Iframe as it is an external catalogue not into a DIV because I have to use javascript or ajax; again cross site security issues. I think PHP would work

Comment: well, in this case, the solution I'd see is: using a php script as iframe source (for example, call it "searchresults.php"), reload the iframe source page once you submit the searchbox using the inputted string as a query parameter reloading the script (for example something like "searchresults.php?searchfor=inputstring") the php script shall return results based upon the that an list them. Triggering iframe source reload could be done by javascript on click search button click, or by php submitting the whole page once you click it.